# How do I disable "activities" for a custom module on SugarCRM 6.5+ 7+

Tags: module, sugarcrm

The title is pretty clear but again: How do I disable "activities" for a custom module on SugarCRM 6.5+ 7+

I have a module containing millions of records and activities has been slowing it down to a breaking point. I managed to stop the activities through some hacking (deleting entries from the cache folder) but I would like to know how to do it the right way so on repair&rebuild + etc things will be normal/ok.

//edit1:
I'm happy to completely disable activities for a limited period of time while my script runs and then enable it again right after if that is possible.

Comment: When you say disable Activities are you referring to the grouping of Calls, Tasks, Notes, Emails and Meetings? Or are you talking about users interacting with the module as activities? Hook me up with a bit more info and I'll try to help!

Comment: well, I think I meant activity stream. It's a table called activities which has a json field etc. My script starts very fast but then slows down drastically after 10 minutes probably because the activity stream starts to get updated etc from a queue created on each save. This table is like a history of everything that happens with each module etc.

Comment: Ahhhh. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to disable activities (activity stream, known in the past as sugar feed I think).

As my problem was running a script on 100k records etc disabling the whole activity stream temporarily in the beginning of the script and then turning it back on in the end was sufficient.

It's quite simple and it feels like an embarrassment I didn't look into the activity stream's source before since in order to disable it a simple:

```
Activity::disable();
```

does the job and to turn it back on:

```
Activity::enable();
```

There is also a "blacklist" array in the source etc but 1- It didn't solve the problem and 2- It's clearly not upgrade safe etc.